# sqlplus connection to 11g DB

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Oracle 11g2 64-bit Database installed on windows server 2008.
Oracle 6i Form Developer installed on windows server 2003.
There is DB connection problem from client PC.

I add my DB SID(orcl2008) in tnsnames.ora file on client machine.

When Open cmd and

```
C:\>tnsping80 orcl2008

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows:
<c> Copyright 1997 Oracle Corporation.
Attempting to connect<ADDRESS=<PROTOCOL=TCP><HOST=192.168.15.100><Port=1521>>OK<0 msec>
```

But when connect DB using sqlplus then cmd disappear.

```
   
C:\>sqlplus scott/123@orcl2008
```

As press enter then CMD screen disappear immediately.

And when I try to connect Form 6i with using:

```
U:scott
P:123
H:orcl2008
```

this form also disappear.

Kindly help me, connect 11g2 Database instance with sqlplus and Form 6i.

Answer (score 0):

Pinging always confirms whther the service is running or not. It does not mean that it allows remote connections. Check your configuration to allow remote connections, then try out again.

Comment: how configure to allow remote connections?

Comment: recommend you to see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/network.htm#CHDBHJGJ)

Comment: If you have sevral client application its possible that you are updating the wrong tnsnames.ora. check your enviorment variable ` bin` and make sure that the right client is first in line.